# sending multiple messages in android continously

Tags: android, sms

I am new to android and working on a application in which i have list of inbox messages from the phone(user will be able to select more than one message using checkbox) then user will be able to select the person to whom he should send these messages and send message to him.Please tell him how can i send more than one message to a person continously at a same time.Please help me any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

store messages in an array
and send them

```
for(int i =0; i<=msgarray.length(); i++)

{
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, msg[i], null, null);

}
```